# SSRS Combining values within columns to a comma delimited single row when grouped

Tags: formatting, report, multiple-columns, ssrs-tablix

I managed to Combining values within columns to a comma delimited single row, but this row is repeated for the group.  Is there anyway I can restrict it to display the one row?
So it start off like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZlb2.jpg)
And I want to have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Lrp.jpg)

After using adding a parent group and using =Join(LookupSet(Fields!Company.Value,Fields!Company.Value,Fields!SubCert.Value,"DataSet Name"),","), I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPD3i.png)

How to I hide the repeated rows in the second column?
Thank you.